rowsums for columns with specific characters when there are only NAs
I have this dataframe
df <- data.frame(var1=c(NA, 3, 3, 4, 0),
                 var2=c(NA, 2, 5, 3, NA),
                 var3=c(NA, 3, 6, 6, NA),
                 var4=c(NA, 1, 2, 14, NA))
df
 var1 var2 var3 var4
1   NA   NA   NA   NA
2    3    2    3    1
3    3    5    6    2
4    4    3    6   14
5    0   NA   NA   NA

I want to sum each row. So I do the following
df %>%   mutate(sumVar = select(., contains("var")) %>% rowSums(,na.rm=T)) 

and I get
  var1 var2 var3 var4 sumVar
1   NA   NA   NA   NA      0
2    3    2    3    1      9
3    3    5    6    2     16
4    4    3    6   14     27
5    0   NA   NA   NA      0

you can see that the sum of the first row that contains only NAs is zero! How can I fix that?
I have  "contains" because my real data set contains 500 columns so I want to select those that start with "var". In that case, it is correct to use "contains"?

Would you want a row like the first to have NA? In the last row, would you want that to be zero or NA? What is the correct value of these rows for this project?

Thank you Kat!. I want to ignore the NAs, when there are numbers, and if I have only NAs to get NA. So in the first row I want NA and in the last zero

Try this: library(hablar); df %>% mutate(sum = apply(., 1, sum_))

We can use rowSums and replace after the fact if_all columns have NAs. There is a starts_with selection helper.
library(dplyr)

df |> 
    mutate(sumVar = rowSums(pick(starts_with('var')), na.rm = TRUE),
           sumVar = replace(sumVar, if_all(starts_with('var'), is.na), NA))

  var1 var2 var3 var4 sumVar
1   NA   NA   NA   NA  NA
2    3    2    3    1   9
3    3    5    6    2  16
4    4    3    6   14  27
5    0   NA   NA   NA   0


You can also achieve the desired result using apply where row values are summed omitting NAs if at least one value is not NA.
df$sumVar <- apply(df[grepl("^var", names(df))], 1, \(x) if(all(is.na(x))) NA else sum(x, na.rm = TRUE))

But if the dataframe is particularly long, we can use ifelse for a little more efficient code. This essentially does the same thing as above albeit vectorially; compute row sums (without NAs) first and replace locations where all values are NA by NA.
cols <- grepl("^var", names(df))
df$sumVar <- ifelse(rowSums(!is.na(df[cols]))==0, NA, rowSums(df[cols], na.rm=TRUE))

both of which produce:
  var1 var2 var3 var4 sumVar
1   NA   NA   NA   NA     NA
2    3    2    3    1      9
3    3    5    6    2     16
4    4    3    6   14     27
5    0   NA   NA   NA      0

Try it online.

Doing row wise calculation can be slow on larger datasets. Try using this :
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(
    sumVar = rowSums(pick(starts_with("var")), na.rm = TRUE), 
    sumVar = ifelse(rowSums(is.na(pick(starts_with("var")))) == 
                            ncol(pick(starts_with("var"))), NA, sumVar)
    )

#  var1 var2 var3 var4 sumVar
#1   NA   NA   NA   NA     NA
#2    3    2    3    1      9
#3    3    5    6    2     16
#4    4    3    6   14     27
#5    0   NA   NA   NA      0



ifelse(all(is.na(c_across(contains("var")))) checks if all the selected columns in the row are NA, if yes, it assigns NA to the sumVar.

sum(c_across(contains("var")), na.rm = TRUE) if there are non-NA values, this calculates the row sum while ignoring NA Values.

Here is the detailed code block:


library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(sumVar = ifelse(all(is.na(c_across(contains("var")))), NA, sum(c_across(contains("var")), na.rm = TRUE))) %>%
  ungroup()


Thank you. Do I need ungroup or I can skip it?

It's good to ungroup() to ensure normal dataframe operations working as expected.

Thank you very much.If I want to select particular columns, for example var3 and var4, how can I modify your code?
